# Print list of words

Tags: python, string, counting

I had to divide up the four letter words based upon the last two letters of the word
(the word ending) and Count up how many words you have for each of these
endings.  I was able to do this part but in the next part
PROBLEM:

1. I need to only work with word endings where there
   are at least 30 words. And print out a list of word endings and the number of words you found for each
   ending, which I have not been able to do because the way I'm doing it gives me a list of the words with the endings and not in the format that i need which is:
   as:30
   as:35
2. I need to Randomly choose one word from those available for each of the word endings
   to use in your stimuli and print a list of all possible words and count them

```py
endings_dict = {}
for word in unique_words:
    endings_dict[word[2:]] = endings_dict.get(word[2:], []) + [word] 

print(endings_dict) 

print({key: len(value) for key, value in endings_dict.items()})
 
for v in endings_dict.values(): #this part doesn't work
   if len(v) >= 30:
        print(v)
```

UPDATE: I was able to correct the code and I believe I also manages to get the random part

```
for key, value in endings_dict.items(): 
   if len(value) >= 30:
        print(key, len(value))

 
import random        
for v in endings_dict.values():
    if len(v) >= 30:
        random.choice(v) 
            print(random.choice(v))
print(len(random.choice(v)))
```

BUT the len part it still not working because it is not giving me the number of all the random words hat were generated

Comment: Get the key and the value using: `for k, v in d.items()`. Print the key and the length of the value.

Comment: Code looks OK and works for me. Try say `>=2` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Just made a small change to your "This Dosent Work" section

We are looking for the exact same outcome as you have here
`print({key: len(value) for key, value in endings_dict.items()})`
but we just want to put a condition on it.

To do so we will use the following. Do understand what is happening it might be useful for you to add a print statement to here to see what `item[0]` and `item[1]` are actually comprised of

```
for item in endings_dict.items():
    if len(item[1]) >= threshold:
        print({item[0]:len(item[1])})
```

This allows us to output in the proper format and apply our condition

the full code with the list i used is as follows

```
unique_words = ["peep","keep","mope","hope","blow","love","beat","meat","plea","flow","brow","mile","file","nile","bile","tile"]
endings_dict = {}
for word in unique_words:
    endings_dict[word[2:]] = endings_dict.get(word[2:], []) + [word] 

print(endings_dict) 

print({key: len(value) for key, value in endings_dict.items()})
threshold = 4
for k,v in endings_dict.items():
    if len(v) >= threshold:
        print({k:len(v)})
```

EDIT:

Re read the question again and saw i missed out on part 2:

```
for k,v in endings_dict.items():
    if len(v)>= threshold:
        endings_pass_dict[k]=v
        endings_pass_formated_dict[k]=len(v)

randomIndex = random.randint(0,len(endings_pass_dict.items())-1)
k = list(endings_pass_dict.keys())
v = list(endings_pass_dict.values())
print(k[randomIndex],v[randomIndex],len(v[randomIndex]))
```